# Codeigniter: unable to link the referencing css file

Tags: css, codeigniter

I am just starting out with Codeigniter. 
I have referenced the css file in the corresponding views file but it fails to link. This is the code I have used to reference the css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
```

I tested the css code by inserting it between  &  and it works. Just can't get the linking to work.

Comment: Do you have the url helper loaded? `$this->load->helper('url');` ?

Comment: yes I did using $this->load->helper('url')
I also autoloaded it. I seem to have the same problem with the images, they don't load either. my css & images files are saved in css & images folder respectively. They are stored on the same level at the system file - root. I hope this can shed more light.

Comment: is this link_tag working something like, `<?php echo link_tag('resources/style.css');?>` inside head tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sorry, rewriting the whole answer as I remember what I had to do and which **should** fix your problem.

Check your .htaccess file in the top level directory, I added exceptions for `js/css/images` dirs otherwise they would have been rewritten:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|images|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Okay tried both - still no luck!
Final html redering for:
base_url() shows www.domain.com/css/style.css
site_url shows www.domain.com/index/css/style.css

Comment: I used your code for .htaccess file and this is the error I get:
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@obsia.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: You should check the error log of the webserver to see the specific error that caused the Internal Server Error. Also, what happens if you try to reach `www.domain.com/css/style.css` directly?

Comment: If I use www.domain.com/css/style.css directly, it gives me a 404 error. If I use this htaccess code it I don't get the internal error when I go to my domain www.obsia.com but ofcourse still does not link the css. RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|user_guide|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: Wait here might be the issue (looking at my error log files). It looks under /home/obisac5/public_html/css to find the css file. Do I change the base url to the above url or will it cause the problem when add other bits of codes to complete the website?

Comment: No you can't use absolute paths in HTML pages, look for other errors related to htaccess rewriting in the log

Comment: I just realised that my main index is in the public_html folder which is at the root level. All my other codeigniter files are at the same level as the public_html file.

Comment: Hey kemp, thanks for being so patient with me. It was error on my part for not having the files on the same level - didnt realize it! It works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(two years later)... For the RewriteRule in the .htaccess file, you want your path starting with your server's root, so for example, if you're using WAMP, and you have a folder at C:\wamp\www\my_site\my_new_app then your RewriteRule should say

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/my_new_app/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Just throwing that out there for us CI newbs